# Spring Tool Suite Getting Started guide does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to do the "Working a Getting Started guide with STS" (here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/)  using Spring Tool Suite (STS) (Version: 3.6.3.RELEASE), and there is no "Import Getting Started Content" wizard in the File menu.  I try to import the "Spring Getting Started Content" and it says it's empty.

I just want to run through the tutorial in the link.
[image]

Comment: It relies on network connectivity to grab the latest guide content. If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that your proxy settings are configured correctly in Eclipse. Are you using an STS distribution? Or did you install the STS components in an existing Eclipse installation?

Comment: I also suspect it is a network connectivity issue. I just tried the "Import Spring Gettings Started Content" wizard and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Configure PROXY settings on **Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections**
Change mode to Manual, enable for https, set proxy host and credentials.

Then **change default Apache httpclient provider** (used by Eclipse update) to JRE URLConnection based provider.

From version Eclipse Kepler (4.3) add system property

```
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

To start eclipse

```
eclipse -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

More info:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422665
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Disabling_Apache_Httpclient

Answer (score 2):

I just try this and it works now, great!

Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Change mode to Manual

Answer (score 0):

For me I have used

> Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Change mode to Direct

and it works now, great!