# port out of range -1 when trying to import with Spring Tools Suite

Tags: linux, spring, eclipse

I've just installed STS on my linux mint machine. When I tried to import a getting strated content (File -> New -> import a getting strated content), I ended up with this [image]

Internet semms fine and I'm not using any proxy or something like that

`uname -a` output :

```
Linux sn4ke 4.5.2-040502-generic #201604200335 SMP Wed Apr 20 07:37:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Hello jww,

This is actually not related to a code I wrote. It's pure Eclipse/STS UI if I may say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had to tweak the proxy setting : **Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Change mode to Manual**

I wonder why they didn't set it to manual by default...

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36732738/2300596